# Needed the details about the Image(Media) in Twilio Api

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm setting up a server for the WhatsApp using Twilio API. As I'm sending the media file from the WhatsApp to Twilio it doesn't show any details about it, while sending a text it shows the details in the body.
The response I getting while sending the images is:

```
body:
      { SmsMessageSid: 'SM94cXXXX8f8d18a8dbf809cXXXXXXXXXX',
       NumMedia: '0',
        SmsSid: 'SM94cXXXX8f8d18a8dbf809cXXXXXXXXXX',
        SmsStatus: 'received',
        Body: '',
        To: 'whatsapp:+14XXXXXXXXX',
        NumSegments: '1',
        MessageSid: 'SM94cXXXX8f8d18a8dbf809cXXXXXXXXXX',
        AccountSid: 'ACXXXXXX6f5f98b5adc708d57aedXXXXXX',
        From: 'whatsapp:+9199XXXXXXXX',
        ApiVersion: '2010-04-01' },
     _body: true,
     length: undefined,
     read: [Function],
     route: Route { path: '/sms', stack: [Array], methods: [Object] } },
  locals: {},
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  statusCode: 200,
  [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
   { 'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
     'content-type': [ 'Content-Type', 'image/jpeg' ] } }
```

While The response I got while sending the text is:

```
body:
    { SmsMessageSid: 'SMd7b60aXXXXXXc830a894c5e91XXXXXXX',
            NumMedia: '0',
            SmsSid: 'SMd7b60aXXXXXXc830a894c5e91XXXXXXX',
            SmsStatus: 'received',
            Body: 'Hello',
            To: 'whatsapp:+14XXXXXXXXX',
            NumSegments: '1',
            MessageSid: 'SMd7b60aXXXXXXc830a894c5e91XXXXXXX',
            AccountSid: 'ACXXXXXX6f5f98b5adc708d57aedXXXXXX',
            From: 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXXX',
            ApiVersion: '2010-04-01' }
```

The Code used is :

```
const http = require('http');
    const express = require('express');
    const accountSid = 'XXXXXXXX';
    const authToken = 'XXXXXXXX';
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
    const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.post("/sms",function(req,res){
            rt(req,res);
    });
    function rt (req,res){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
        console.log(res);
    }
     http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
      console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
    });
```

Please provide the help How to get details about images from the response.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the moment, Twilio [does not support incoming media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#receiving-a-whatsapp-message) in WhatsApp messages. This support is being worked on and should be out soon.